# Outer observable never complete or finalized

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have two observables. How do I execute them sequentially and get the completed event one after another?
I've tried concatMap, but it seems didn't work as I expected.

```js
    this._activatedRouteService.queryParams
      .pipe(
        concatMap((params) => {
          console.log('start');
          if (typeof params['q'] === 'string') this._searchQuery = params['q'];
          else this._searchQuery = null;

          return this._postService
            .searchPosts(this._searchQuery!)
            .pipe(finalize(() => console.log('inner finalize')));
        }),
        finalize(() => {
          console.log('outer finalize');
        })
      )
      .subscribe(
        (response) => {
          this._posts = response?.data ?? this._posts;
        },
        (error) => {
          if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
            this._snackBarService.open(
              'Failed to fetch posts.\n' +
                (error.error?.message ?? 'Unknown error.'),
              undefined,
              {
                duration: SnackBarConfig.ERROR_DURATIONS,
              }
            );
          } else {
            this._snackBarService.open(
              'Failed to fetch posts.\nUnknown error.',
              undefined,
              {
                duration: SnackBarConfig.ERROR_DURATIONS,
              }
            );
          }
        },
        () => {
          console.log('outer complete');
        }
      );
```

But `outer finalize` or `outer complete` is never called.

Comment: use switchMap operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `outer finalize` is never logged is that `_activatedRouteService.queryParams` never completes. It's a hot observable.

If you want the observable to complete after you execute the inner observable once, I recommend the `take()` operator. It will "take" any number of values emitted from the observable before sending a complete signal.

Try adding `take(1),` on the line before your `concatMap()`.

Comment: It worked, but could share more details about this? Or share any references?

Comment: Here's some information about subscriptions which involves the `complete` event: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/concepts/rxjs-primer#subscription And here's the info on the `take()` operator: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/take

Comment: The `finally()` operator doesn't trigger unless the observable sends a `complete` signal. But not all observables may `complete`. It is important to understand what kind of observable you're working with. For example, an observable based on user's mouse movement will never `complete`. But the observable created from an http request will `complete` after emitting one value.